# How do i reuse event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I got a code:

```
private void border1_PreviewGiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    // some code
}
```

mainwindow.xaml:

```xml
<Border BorderBrush="Silver" PreviewGiveFeedback="border1_PreviewGiveFeedback"
        Name="border1" />
```

Now i want to reuse the event handler in border1 inside border2 (without writig the same code in border2 and cs file) What to write here:

```xml
<Border Name="border2" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the same as you use in the first border

```xml
<Border PreviewGiveFeedback="border1_PreviewGiveFeedback" Name="border2" />
```

Comment: @divfe, why should there be any conflict?

Comment: @divfe no there are no confilcts

Answer (score 1):

The `PreviewGiveFeedback` property is simply asking for an event handler with a certain signature.  You could actually name it `Potatoes_AreTasty__YUM` and it would function perfectly well as long as it had the proper signature.

Thus, the way to use it in border2 is to just give it the same event method as border1.  You could also re-name the function to indicate that it isn't exclusively for border1 but a generic border preview event handler.

Comment: I though VS does something more than just add this code. So than i can write everything by hand also.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio to design your controls and you say "Create an event handler" it will stub out a method with the appropriate signature and add the appropriate attribute to the control itself.  These are the only two changes needed to wire an event handler to a control.  Thus, you can just wire any control to use that same event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the same:

```xml
<Border Name="border2" PreviewGiveFeedback="border1_PreviewGiveFeedback" />
```

is going to work. You should consider renaming the event handler method in that case, though.

Comment: Can i reuse also static resource and similar things ?

Comment: @divfe, sure, resources are mostly useful when they are reused.